# How would you train YoloV3 or YoloV4 on images of size 8280X6208

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, yolo, yolov4

I am trying to train Yolo on 8k images but resizing images to 416 by 416 loses a lot of information. Is there a way to grid search on the images before passing it as training and then putting them back together after inference ?